# Adding span tags to post titles using regex

Tags: regex

My basic titles are something like

Part One: Part Two

And I'm trying to end up with something like this using the colon as what I find in the regex:

```
<span class="one-class">Part One:</span><br><span class="two-class">Part Two</span>
```

This is the original in `entry-header.php` and I want to continue to have that html:

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        }
```

The following works as long as there is a colon in the title. If there is no colon, then none of the html gets added.

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
                        $string = get_the_title();
            $pattern = '~(.+): (.+)~i';
            $replacement = '<h1 class="entry-title"><span class="title-cite-pali">$1:</span><br><span class="title-english">$2</span></h1>';
            echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
        }
```

But I think what I really want is the following, ***but it doesn't work***. The output is as if my added code is not there.

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
            $string = the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title test">', '</h1>' );
            $pattern = '~(.+): (.+)~i';
            $replacement = '<span class="title-cite-pali">$1:</span><br><span class="title-english">$2</span>';
            echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
            
        }
```

I think if I could get the above code working, it is preferable since if there was no colon at least the `h1` tags would be added.

Comment: If you want `the_title()` function to return its result instead of echoing it, you should use `$string = the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title test">', '</h1>', false );`

Comment: so do you need to allow for the case with no colon? what should happen then? why not just add that case to your first piece of code if it's working ;-)

Comment: You don't need regex, just split the string by the `:` character and wrap the array items in span tags. A regular expression is just overcomplicating it ( and you shouldn't parse HTML with regex anyway )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice to use regex, but you can also achieve the same thing here by just splitting the string on `':'` with `explode` e.g.:

```php
    $matches = explode(":", get_the_title()) ;

    if (count($matches) == 2) {
       $result = "foo bar $matches[0] foo bar $matches[1]";
    } else {
       // case with no : in title
       $result = "foo bar $matches[0] foo bar";
    }
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks! Any time regex can be avoided I guess it should. I've tried to implement your solution but WP is kicking out the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL) in ... line 48. That line is `if (count($matches)) == 2) `

Comment: oops, yep one too many `)` .. updated the answer, try again ;-)

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I think I will go with your solution as it seems to be the most straightforward to understand.

Comment: @HopefullCoder cool, glad it worked. Upvotes and accepted answers appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex.

First, grab the title as a string variable:

```php
$title = get_the_title();
```

Then, find the location of the first colon:

```php
$colon = strpos( $title, ':' );
```

If there is no colon, handle that:

```php
if ( $colon === FALSE ) {
    // there was no colon, handle that!
    echo '<h2>' . esc_html( $title ) . '</h2>';
} else {
    // the rest of the code
}
```

What about the rest of the code that goes in the `else`? Well, lets split it in two:

```php
$first_part = substr( $title, 0, $colon );
$second_part = substr( $title, $colon + 1, strlen( $title ) );
```

Now we can output them differently:

```php
echo '<span>' . $first_part . '</span>';
echo '<span>' . $second_part . '</span>';
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I will go with the explode answer since it is simpler, but I may need to return to your answer if my requirements get more complicated.